# How to authorize pool in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Trying use my own create agent for the first time, met with this:

> The pipeline is not valid. Could not find a pool with name Default. The pool does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

I have 2 agents in the Default pool in idle status. I follow https://aka.ms/yamlauthz but it tells me nothing about how to authorize the pool.

How do I authorize the pool?

Comment: Can you share the yaml file?

Answer (score 4):

If clicking on 'Authorize' does not help, it may be because the agent pool has not been added to the project, only to the organization (agent pools are shared across organizations).

Go to Project settings -> Agent Pools -> Add pool, then Pool to link: Existing and select the agent pool to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve this issue by doing the following : Open the build pipeline editor in the UI. Set the default branch to the branch where you updated the YAML file. Save the pipeline. This would authorize all resources such as Default pool. Then, you can switch the branch back to the default branch and save the pipeline again.

This is explained a bit more in this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshoot-yaml-build-first-run).Hope this helps.